# Finding specific string is odd or even from an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to find an odd string from an given array.

**Code :**

```js
const friendArray = ["agdum", "bagdum", "chagdum", "lagdum", "jagdum", "magdum"];

function oddFriend(friendArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < friendArray.length; i++) {
    if (friendArray[i].length % 2 != 0) {
      return friendArray[i];
    }
  }
}
const myFriend = oddFriend(friendArray);
console.log(myFriend);
```

Comment: You have succeeded in finding the first odd-length string in your array. What is the problem?

Comment: Your function returns the first odd-length string from the array. If you want to return all of them, use `friendArray.filter()`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior trying more and more for this question. I post because i didn’t find out the exact problem here.

Comment: You need to explain the problem.

Comment: The code you provided does exactly what you're asking: find an odd-length string from a given array. Your question needs to explain in what way your code isn't giving the expected result. If you just solved this question yourself, and wanted to document the solution here for other people to find: [That's not a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but to do that you need to first ask the question as a question, and then add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this:

```
const friendArray = ["agdum","bagdum","chagdum","lagdum","jagdum","magdum",];

  function oddFriend(friendArray) {
    if (friendArray.length % 2 != 0) {
      return friendArray;
    }
  }
  const myFriend = friendArray.filter(oddFriend);
  console.log(myFriend);
```

Comment: The argument to `oddFriend()` is a string, not an array. It's also very confusing to use the same name for the parameter as the array you're looping over.

Answer (score 0):

`.flatMap()` and a ternary callback makes a simple and readable filter. It's not entirely clear if you wanted only odd or odd and even so there's both versions.

**Odd length strings**

```js
const fArray = ["agdum", "bagdum", "chagdum", "lagdum", "jagdum", "magdum"];

let odd = fArray.flatMap(o => o.length % 2 === 1 ? [o] : []);

console.log(odd);
```

**Odd & even length strings**

```js
const fArray = ["agdum", "bagdum", "chagdum", "lagdum", "jagdum", "magdum"];

let oe = [[], []];

fArray.forEach(o => o.length % 2 === 1 ? oe[0].push(o) : oe[1].push(o));

console.log(oe);
```

Comment: Why use flatmap instead of filter?

Comment: It's very easy to return various values and having the option to not return on an iteration is simple with `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which will create a new array with all odd friends that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
// Input array
const friendArray = ["agdum", "bagdum", "chagdum", "lagdum", "jagdum", "magdum"];

// Filtered result
console.log(friendArray.filter((friend) => friend.length % 2 !== 0));
```